# Calculate look back period using pandas

Tags: pandas, lookback

I need to look back backwards in each row for a different time and count new patients, so its like I look back from a date and check new patients in last month then check new patients in second last month and so on.

My data set is something like this:
 In this image, I want to start from last RX_FILL_DT and then check from last month to two years
[This is my Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xt7dT.png)

This is my Data Set

> PATIENT_Id > RX_FILL_DT > RX_QUANTITY >   DAYS_SUPPLY
>
> 106208 > 3/25/2010 >  20  >   30
>
> 1240316 > 5/15/2010 > 15  >   30
>
> 1381727 > 8/26/2010 > 10  >   28
>
> 1381727 > 1/17/2010 > 10  >   28
>
> 1381808 > 6/6/2010 >  30  >   30
>
> 1381938 > 4/16/2010 > 45  >   90
>
> 1381938 > 8/3/2010 > 15   >   30
>
> 1381938 > 9/4/2010 > 15   >   30
>
> 1381938 > 9/14/2010 > 15  >   30
>
> 1381938 > 9/30/2010 > 15  >   27
>
> 1381961 > 6/8/2010 > 15   >   25
>
> 1381961 > 7/1/2010 > 15   >   23
>
> 1381961 > 7/8/2010 > 15   >   25
>
> 1381961 > 7/28/2010 > 15  >   23
>
> 1381961 > 8/19/2010 > 15  >   25
>
> Max Date    9/30/2010

And my output should look like this:

> ```
>              lookback 1 month >   lookback 2 month    >lookback 3 months
> ```
>
> No of new patients          >     0      >     0        >         0
>   [Lookback calculation can been seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9x2a.png)

[New Patients = post - common (between prior and post)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlmDs.png)

Here the patient is new if they don't have any record in look back time frame.

For eg, for a look back of one month, a particular patient id has only one entry then it means the patient is new and is counted when lookback is one month.

Please help I am new to pandas.

My code is like this:

> onlyDip = pd.read_table("C:\Users\aa18957\Desktop\Transactions.txt", sep = "|" )
>
> onlyDip['RX_FILL_DT'] = pd.to_datetime(onlyDip['RX_FILL_DT'])

I am trying to use pandas.Series.rolling but I am not sure how to make it count new patients.

Comment: I think you should post a dummy df , your code and the desired output, users should be able to replicate your issue. Thank you. :) [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Aayushi, Please post the source code of your panda script!

Comment: I have edited it to resemble my output and I don't have any dummy code as I am not sure how to start solving this problem.

Comment: @AayushiAgarwal Please make it more clear how we identify the new patient.

Comment: I have added an image showing output and how to identify new patients, hope this helps